# How to query Cryptokitties metadata from Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, erc-721, cryptokitties

I;m trying to query a Cryptokitties token metadata from Etherscan and I need to give two values:
`_tokenId (uint256)` and `_preferredTransport (string)`.

What are possible value for `_preferredTransport`?

Comment: hello, do you finally find how to query kitty's metadata?

Comment: Nope. But you can get some info through the getKitty query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like it's deprecated (no longer in use)](https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#code):

```
function tokenMetadata(uint256 _tokenId, string _preferredTransport) external view returns (string infoUrl) {
    require(erc721Metadata != address(0));
    bytes32[4] memory buffer;
    uint256 count;
    (buffer, count) = erc721Metadata.getMetadata(_tokenId, _preferredTransport);

    return _toString(buffer, count);
}

function getMetadata(uint256 _tokenId, string) public view returns (bytes32[4] buffer, uint256 count) {
    if (_tokenId == 1) {
        buffer[0] = "Hello World! :D";
        count = 15;
    } else if (_tokenId == 2) {
        buffer[0] = "I would definitely choose a medi";
        buffer[1] = "um length string.";
        count = 49;
    } else if (_tokenId == 3) {
        buffer[0] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mi e";
        buffer[1] = "st accumsan dapibus augue lorem,";
        buffer[2] = " tristique vestibulum id, libero";
        buffer[3] = " suscipit varius sapien aliquam.";
        count = 128;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the 2nd input argument has no name, and is there for not in use.

Comment: Thanks! — and now how would I request the metadata from Etherscan? as a value is required for `preferredTransport`

Comment: @PmRivière: "not in use" means that you can pass whatever you want, and it will have no impact on the result!

Comment: It looks like `erc721Metadata` is address(0), so `tokenMetadata` will fail no matter what. I think `getKitty` is the how you should get data about the token

Comment: @flygoing: Yes, it means that function `tokenMetadata` will always revert (until someone changes this currently null pointer). But you've asked a general question about a function which takes "`_tokenId (uint256)` and `_preferredTransport (string)`" (without specifying anything beyond that BTW, not even the contract address which I had to look up myself). And I have answered that question. If you have another question about another function, then you should post it separately, and accept this answer if you feel it has answered the your question. Otherwise, please explain what else is missing.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for the answer and sorry I didn't produce the contract address