# How does Opensea fetch Cryptokitties' metadata?

Tags: solidity, nft, cryptokitties, meta-data

As far as know CryptoKitties doesn't have metadatas on blockchain, they generating images from kitty's genes. Am I right?

But here is the real question: If they don't have metadata on blockchain how Opensea fetch their metadata?

Comment: See this comment to another question. Seems like it's only queried from their backend now, and smart-contract only returns encoded genes (see `geneScience` contract to decode)
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82726/how-to-query-cryptokitties-metadata-from-etherscan#comment102702_82727